# Converting an elgg 1.7 theme to use on 1.8

Tags: elgg

I have a 1.7 Elgg theme which needs to be installed on Elgg 1.8.

Is this possible?

I have installed the theme module on 1.8 and it seems that there is no css being picked up. I have read that in 1.8 the way CSS modification are done has changed.

I thank you for your advice.

Thanks

Regards
Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the [Elgg docs about themes](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Themes).